# event.persist is not a function in React 16

Tags: reactjs, events

I am using Jodit Editor in my react , everything works fine until When I click outside of Editor I am getting this error

**ERROR : event.persist is not a function**

I am using React v16 and here it is my code , I have tried to add event.persist on onChange but it does not work for my scenario.

Initially this was coming as an warning in console but later on it started showing in view as well and blocking the page with message I mentioned above

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";
import LightToolTip from "../LightToolTip";
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react';


const config = {
  toolbar: true,
  useSplitMode: false,
  showXPathInStatusbar: false,
  showCharsCounter: false,
  showWordsCounter: false,
  showPlaceholder: false,
  showTooltip: true,
  allowShortcut: true,
  allowPaste: true,
  allowPasteImage: false,
  uploader: {
    insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
  },
  disablePlugins: 'paste',
};

const RichTextEditor = ({
  id,
  label,
  fmoId,
  isDefault,
  isAdmin,
  defaultValue,
  textValue,
  resourceId,
  updateParentValue,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputVal(textValue || "")
  }, [fmoId, textValue]);

  const updateInputVal = (value) => {
    if (value != null) {
      setInputVal(value);
      updateParentValue(id, value, resourceId, false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <LightToolTip title={!isAdmin ? "" : `Key: ${id}`}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={id}>
          {label} 
        </InputLabel>
      </LightToolTip>
      {!isDefault ? (
        <LightToolTip title={`Default: ${defaultValue || "No Default Found"}`}>
          <JoditEditor
            id={id}
            name={id}
            value={inputVal}
            config={config}
            onChange={event => updateInputVal(event)}
          />
        </LightToolTip>
      )
        :
      
          <JoditEditor
            id={id}
            name={id}
            value={inputVal}
            config={config}
            onChange={(value) => updateInputVal(value)}
           
          />
      }
     
    </>
  );
};

export default RichTextEditor;
```

This is the code of my package-json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.12",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.15",
    "jodit-react": "^1.3.39",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^5.7.2",
    "react-html-email": "^3.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

}

This is ToolTip Code

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const LightTooltip = withStyles((theme) => ({
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
      fontSize: 11,
    },
}))(Tooltip);


const LightToolTip = ({children, title}) => {
    return (
        <LightTooltip title={title} placement="bottom-start">
            {children}
        </LightTooltip>
    );
};

export default LightToolTip;
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error. Buts its not showing any error. You can check https://codesandbox.io/s/new-https-k17r68. If you can provide more code in sandbox which reproduce the issue then someone can help.

Comment: It produces error in console , I have added the complete code of file , check new code now

Comment: Please provide code of `LightToolTip`. Also provide your package.json file to check version of package you using.

Comment: I have added it , check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes with `LightTooltip` component. You have used `@material-ui/core/Tooltip` class in that. Which adds tooltip to children.

**Tooltip** has 2 trigger points. hover(mouseenter/mouseleave) and focus(focus/blur). On both events mouseleave/blur is called `handleLeave` function on Tooltip.

on blur event, it's getting event but as its `RichTextEditor` it's passing editor HTML as event due to that you getting the error `event.persist is not a function`.

To fix the issue you should disable the focus/blur event on `Tooltip`.

Updated code as following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";
import LightToolTip from "../LightToolTip";
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const config = {
  toolbar: true,
  useSplitMode: false,
  showXPathInStatusbar: false,
  showCharsCounter: false,
  showWordsCounter: false,
  showPlaceholder: false,
  showTooltip: true,
  allowShortcut: true,
  allowPaste: true,
  allowPasteImage: false,
  uploader: {
    insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
  },
  disablePlugins: "paste",
};

const RichTextEditor = ({
  id,
  label,
  fmoId,
  isDefault,
  isAdmin,
  defaultValue,
  textValue,
  resourceId,
  updateParentValue,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputVal(textValue || "");
  }, [fmoId, textValue]);

  const updateInputVal = (value) => {
    if (value != null) {
      setInputVal(value);
      updateParentValue(id, value, resourceId, false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <LightToolTip title={!isAdmin ? "" : `Key: ${id}`}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={id}>{label}</InputLabel>
      </LightToolTip>
      {!isDefault ? (
        <LightToolTip
          title={`Default: ${defaultValue || "No Default Found"}`}
          disableFocusListener // Added to disable focus/blur
        >
          <JoditEditor
            id={id}
            name={id}
            value={inputVal}
            config={config}
            onChange={(event) => updateInputVal(event)}
          />
        </LightToolTip>
      ) : (
        <JoditEditor
          id={id}
          name={id}
          value={inputVal}
          config={config}
          onChange={(value) => updateInputVal(value)}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default RichTextEditor;
```

As `disableFocusListener` property added we need to pass it to `Tooltip` class. So need to update `LightToolTip`.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

const LightTooltip = withStyles((theme) => ({
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
    fontSize: 11,
  },
}))(Tooltip);

const LightToolTip = ({ children, title, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <LightTooltip title={title} placement="bottom-start" {...props}>
      {children}
    </LightTooltip>
  );
};

export default LightToolTip;
```

I recommend **as the tooltip is not visible on RichTextEditor, so you should remove that code.**